# PHP showing blob image loaded by sql on safari

Tags: php, html, image, base64, blob

I want to show blob images via php
my code:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($File['image']).'"/>
```

so nothing special, it works fine for firefox and co.
But the image isn't showing at safari. no error at the console.

Comment: Does it work with Chrome? If so, then Safari is the problem. :P

Comment: yes it works on chrome